# SVN update from command line

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'd like to do the SVN update from a batch file:

I know the following data :

- SVN repro URL
- working directory  (where to copy local file)
- username
- password
- depth full recursive

After I studied [SVN HELP](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw) I still failed to write a proper command line statement to execute the update from a batch file. Can someone write the correct statement for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the initial check out you can use:

```
svn co --username {username} -- password {password} --no-auth-cache {url_to_repo} {working directory for local folder}
```

You will need to permanently accept any SSL certificates here (if using an https url).

Then from within the working directory in a batch file run the command:

```
svn up --username {username} -- password {password} --no-auth-cache
```